# When is (x || !x) false?

Tags: c, boolean, logic, conditional-statements, boolean-logic

A friend of mine jokingly asked me this question. It was meant to be a "goes without saying" type remark, but then I actually thought about it for a while and started coming up with some clever "*almost* solutions".

First attempt:

> If **C** ever supports quantum computing there may be an answer to this. A q-bit can be in many states at once, so it could be false AND true and this conditional will return `(BOOL)0.5` aka "Yes/no/maybe-so" - but once you observe the variable the whole thing will collapse and become invalid again.

Second attempt:

> If X could somehow be defined as a random binary generator and you cast it to a BOOL you could get false some of the time. I'm not sure if you can do this though in **C** unless you use **CLANG**. `#define x (BOOL)!!(rand()%2)`

---

---

The language we were discussing this in is **C** but I'm also curious if anyone can find any solutions in *any* language.

Comment: Answer: Undefined Behavior.

Comment: That's the question Hamlet was asking hundreds of years ago: `bb || !bb`.

Comment: @nsilent22 I laughed a little hardhard 

Comment: The expression can be false if undefined behaviour occurs or if the value is unspecified.

Comment: You can forget about your quantum computing explanation: If `x` is a superposition of true and false, then `!x` will be *entangled* with `x`, ie. measuring `!x` will produce true precisely when measuring `x` yields false, and vice versa. Computing an or on these two entangled qbits will result in a qbit that's quite classically true. (That is the beauty of quantum computers: they allow computation of a function with all possible inputs at once. But the computations are still logically sound.)

Comment: @nsilent22 Actually it was `0x2B | ~0x2B`, which we all know is -1 on a two's-complement machine.

Comment: `#define x (BOOL)!!(rand()%2)` --> in C : `#define x (rand()%2)` is sufficient.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

When `x` is volatile (`volatile int x`) and is modified by an external thread / device, the expression can be **false**.

Comment: Interesting solution! I wonder if there is  a way to do it without directly modifying the variable at another point in the code

Comment: As I pointed out, if `x` is mapped to an externally modified memory location / register, it can happen "spontaneously"

Comment: Oh you're right! That's pretty genius! Although it wont *always* be false, hmm

Comment: @AlbertRenshaw you didn't ask about always, you asked *when*.

Answer (score 9):

It's a bit of a trick, but the following solution also works:

```
#define x 1 ? 0 : 1
(x || !x)
```

The reason is in the operator precedence.  After preprocessing `(x || !x)` resolves to the following (parentheses added to show the precedence):

```
(1 ? 0 : (1 || !1) ? 0 : 1)
```

Comment: This is brilliant - fav answer so far

Comment: You can make it even simpler: `#define x 1&&0` or even `#define x 1,0`

Answer (score 5):

Macros are really cheating here, but you don't need anything to do with boolean types or special compilers.  The following, as far as I know, is legal standard C.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int f(void) { 
  static int y = 0;
  if (y == 0) {
     y = 1;
     return 0;
  } else {
    return 1;
  }
} 

#define x f()

int main(void) {
  if (x || !x) {
    puts("It was true");
  } else {
    puts("It was false");
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Or even more concisely:

```
int y = 0;
#define x y++
```

(For those worried about undefined behavior, note there is a sequence point between the left and right side of `||`.)

Comment: I was working on something like this using CLANG in Obj-C. I got this far `#define x (BOOL)[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:@"x"];[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger:(int)!(BOOL)[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:@"x"] forKey:@"x"];[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];` before realizing I can't have functions inside conditionals in objective-c (as far as I know)

Comment: @AlbertRenshaw: I don't have a clue what that does, but it seems waaaaaaaaay overcomplicated.

Comment: Late reply but it stores the value to memory and flips the value each time its read

Answer (score 5):

An even simpler macro:

```
#define x 0&0
```

expanding `(x || !x)` gives `(0 & 0 || !0 & 0)` which is always false.

Similarly:

```
#define x 0*0
#define x 1*0  // for binary buffs
#define x 4&2  // for HHGG fans.
```

I could not find a 2 letter macro :(

Answer (score 1):

Tried in JS:

```
var i = 0

i++ || !(i++)
```

Note: this solution works only when `i = 0`